# Excel VBA 2 inputs files each opend and copied with diffrent format instead of same

Tags: excel, vba

I have some reports downloaded from SAP as .xls (in same structure and format cells). I have macro which open each file a copy it to one "data" sheet. One file is copied correctly value "1" in cell with format "General" is copied and paste as "1" but values from other input files are opened, copied and paste as 10000000. I don't know why. Any suggestons? Thanks for your help.

```
Sub open_copy_data()

Workbooks.Open FileName:=macro_link & "\" & file_name
Sheets(1).Copy After:=Workbooks(macro_name).Sheets(Workbooks(macro_name).Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Left(file_name, 31), ".xlsx", "")
Workbooks(file_name).Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Open each SAP .xls file and check contents and format. If they are OK, then step through your code with the debugger and check the sheets in each step.

Comment: I have found out that when all the files are open by duoble click, all values are corecct. When is the broken file is open throught file -> open, the  wizard has determined that my data is Delimited. I tiried to add to my code: Format:=1 (and other options), but put all values to one cell and the second one has zero numbers only. How can I fix this?